# Can you use the past perfect from a present reference point?

Tags: grammar, writing, past-perfect

I often find myself using past perfect in a sort of stylized way that I can't justify logically. I am writing a short description of the Matrix, and what I *want* to say is:

> In the film, a programmer and hacker named Neo **takes** a red pill and **realizes** that everything he **had believed** to be true is a lie.

Notice that the sentence is in the present tense overall, yet I'm using the past perfect in the second clause. This isn't usually done. Usually, past perfect is used  from a past point of reference.

So why am I doing this? To use the present perfect here would sound weird. I suppose I should just go with past simple "everything he believed to be true", but it doesn't have the same backward-jumping punch, if you know what I mean.

Are there any examples of such "nonstandard" uses of the past perfect? I feel like I've seen this before. Is there any defense for it?

Answer (score 0):

> Notice that the sentence is in the present tense overall.

This has absolutely no bearing whatsoever on the tense in the noun clause *"that everything [that] he had believed to be true is a lie"* which is the complement of "realizes". (In fact, it is a content clause: it tells you the content of what he realized.)

More than that, *"[that] he had believed to be true is a lie"* is a relative clause modifying "everything".

Relative clauses are subordinate clauses, and tenses in subordinate clauses are not dependent upon the tense in the main clause.

Consider

Neo takes a red pill and realizes that everything [that] he **will believe** to be true is a lie.

Neo takes a red pill and realizes that everything [that] he **believes** to be true is a lie.

Neo takes a red pill and realizes that everything [that] he **has believed** to be true is a lie.

Etc.

Comment: I agree with you @Greybeard, but often grammar books say the past perfect is used for one event that occurred before another event in the past. Would you agree with this definition? If so, what is the event in the past before which Neo's believing occurred?